# 3D-plots of Complex-parametered trig-functions returns empty plot

Tags: plotting, complex, trigonometry

I first tried to plot a parametric equation as follows;

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Zeta[a + b*I]*Cos[Pi*(1 - 2^-(a + b*I))], 
  Zeta[a + b*I]*Sin[Pi*(1 - 2^-(a + b*I))]}, {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}]
```

but I am uncertain if it should work or not. I messed around with it a bit but couldn't get it to work, it just returned an empty plot.

[image: Empty plot from the first input]

I then went and tried other simpler similar plots, which turned out the same way, such as

```
Plot3D[Cos[\[Pi]*(1 - 2^-(a + b*I))], {a, -3, 3}, {b, -3, 3}]
```

and

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Re[Cos[(1 - 2^-(x + 5 I)) π]], Im[Cos[(1 - 2^-(x + 5 I)) π]]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

I am not very used to the Wolfram language, so it could just be that.

Comment: What do you expect to see when the values of the function are complex?

Comment: One of your problems is that your function is merely two dimensional, but it should be three-dimensional in `ParametricPlot3D`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is the sort of thing you want, shown here for your 2nd example:

```
Plot3D[ReIm[Cos[\[Pi]*(1 - 2^-(a + b*I))]], {a, -3, 3}, {b, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Note that function `ReIm` is new as of *Mathematica* 10.1. If you're using an earlier version, you'll need to recreate the effect of that, e.g., by means of `Through[{Re, Im}[ ....] ]`.